# How can I reset system time to network time from the command line?

Tags: 12.04, command-line, time

How can I reset system time to network time from the command line in 12.04 LTS? It's a headless machine, so I don't have access to gui options.

Answer (score 3):

#### ntpdate deprecated

`ntpdate` is deprecated, read more here: http://support.ntp.org/bin/view/Dev/DeprecatingNtpdate

For a one-shot approach

- install the ntp package with `sudo apt-get install ntp`
- set a server in your `/etc/ntp.conf`
- and use `sudo ntpd -q -g -x -n` for a one-time sync.

This also works for deviations up to 68 years.

Alternatively, go to "System Settings" → "Time and Date" (I'm not sure its the correct translation) to enable *Network time*. Note that you can't specify a server there.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**
ntpdate is now deprecated, see @Jan answer for a more secure solution.

Firt of all, you have to install the NTP server (if you don't have it yet) so

```
sudo apt-get install ntp
```

Then, check if ntp is running with

```
sudo service ntp status
```

If it's not running, you can simply type

```
sudo service ntp start
```

Then to update the time

```
sudo ntpdate -u time.nist.gov
```

`time.nist.gov` is not the only one of course. [Here](http://www.pool.ntp.org/) there is a list of timeserver you can alternatively use.
source [here](http://www.tecmint.com/how-to-synchronize-time-with-ntp-server-in-ubuntu-linux-mint-xubuntu-debian/)

Comment: Using `ntpdate` when there's a ntp server running is discouraged and `ntpdate` is deprecated.

Comment: @Jan I didn't know that, I always used this command. Why it is deprecated? Could you provide a link?

Comment: http://support.ntp.org/bin/view/Dev/DeprecatingNtpdate

Comment: @Jan thanks for the info, I've updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

Log in via ssh and type

```
ntpdate 0.europe.pool.ntp.org
```

where 0.europe.pool.ntp.org is the time server for Europe - you could point it to a local one on your network if that's what you need. If you need to install ntp, use

```
sudo apt-get install ntp
```

You could put a script to call the command in a cron job to automate it.

Answer (score 0):

This is the script I use.  Install ntp service if it doesn't come with the distro.  Comment below if ntpdate is dead at some point.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo `sudo systemctl stop ntp.service` > /dev/null
echo `ntpdate -s time.nist.gov` > /dev/null
echo `sudo systemctl start ntp.service` > /dev/null
```

Comment: http://support.ntp.org/bin/view/Dev/DeprecatingNtpdate

Comment: What is the purpose of `echo` in your script?

Comment: with the backtick it just indicates a line of code as opposed to quotes, which just writes to standard out, then you suppress the output by redirecting it to /dev/null, idk, i think maybe you can leave them out on ubuntu?  I know for Centos/RHEL I needed them